# how do we show rating column value in the search results?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, rating

we need to show the rating column from one of our list in the search page,
what is the managed property to the "Rating Column"? 
if not how do we map the property for Rating column to the refinable strings?

Answer (score 1):

There are three Managed Properties in SharePoint Online associated with Rating. They are `AverageRating` mapped to ows_AverageRating, `RatingCount` mapped to ows_RatingCount and `Rating` which is not mapped. In your search results I would use `AverageRating`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB managed property for Rating. Perform below steps:

1. In Admin centre, Click New Managed Property.
2. Enter Rating for the Property Name, select Decimal as the type, click Add Mapping and choose ows_AverageRating(Decimal) as the Crawled property; click OK.
3. Click New Managed Property.
4. Enter Rating Count for the Property Name, select Integer as the type, click Add Mapping and choose ows_RatingCount(Integer) as the Crawled property; click OK.

Wait for full crawl to complete